# How to emulate a linux terminal in a react app

Tags: reactjs, linux, ubuntu, web, liveserver

In my React application I need to emulate a linux server so the user can run some tests. For this tests I need to pre install NMAP and NUCLEI. Does anyone know how I can implement this terminal in a web application?

I want to do something similar to AttackBox from [TryHackMe](https://tryhackme.com/about#:%7E:text=TryHackMe%20is%20an%20online%20platform,cater%20for%20different%20learning%20styles.), but I need only the live server.

This is AttackBox: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbB-0KDLi2o&ab_channel=Joshua17sc

Answer (score 0):

Emulating an entire OS inside the browser is a tall order, you can run a lot of programs in the browser with WASM and you might be able to do something like old console emulators working but emulating a modern linux version in the browser is currently not doable(As far as I know).

The most achievable way to get something close to TryHackMe would be to start virtual machines on demand, for example in AWS, GCP, Azure, or some self hosted solution. And allow your users to connect to these VMs via [noVNC](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC) or a [web based SSH client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH).

You can also provide every user a separate Docker container on a single VM which is cheaper and easier to setup but also more difficult to secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/) library in the browser and connect to the Linux server. On the server, you can run chroot so users will not be able to access the server. Another idea is to run [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) on the backend and each time user connects new container for him is created, but boot time when the user request the access may be longer.